# c++ memcpy read memory

Tags: c++, memcpy

I'm trying to use memcpy to read memory.

```
BYTE test[] = {0x01};
BYTE test2[] = {0x00};
memcpy (test, test2, sizeof(test));
if (test == test2){
    MessageBox::Show("Same");
}else{
    MessageBox::Show("Different");
}
```

Why the test and test2 always different?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your expectation of what `test == test2` would do ?

Comment: The memory addresses will always be different and that is what you are testing

Comment: Prefer standard containers (e.g. [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)) to arrays. Then comparisons like this will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing addresses of `test` and `test2`. Use `memcmp` instead.

Your code is equivalent to

```
if (&test[0] == &test2[0]){
```

Changing it to

```
if (memcmp(test, test2, sizeof(test)) == 0)
```

should work as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are testing equality for the address of the array.  Try using `memcmp` instead.

Answer (score 0):

When the name of an array is used by itself it turns into a pointer, so you're comparing the addresses of the two arrays, not their contents.